# I'm so confused about full disk encryption. help :(

Tags: 12.04, luks

I've been running a live CD of Ubuntu 12.04 for more than a few days now, reading and reading, but I'm not really understanding things when it comes to setting up FDE on Ubuntu 12.04 Precise. I'm sure for the majority of Ubuntu users, it must be quite a simple task. Full disk encryption sounds like a really smart thing to do for security reasons and all.

I'd eventually like to do something like this: http://www.death-zone.org/luks/lukstool though I am not sure if it is possible with Ubuntu.
but my aim is to first get the basics down and then attempt to do the more advanced stuff.

Have a look at this: http://www.death-zone.org/index.php?option=content&task=category&sectionid=2&id=42&Itemid=76 
It's the blog entry that explains the process behind the linked script above.

Comment: If you haven't done this, I'll be going through the process for a newly-ordered SSD sometime today or tomorrow. If I recall, the alternate install disk *does* make this pretty simple, *but* the disk partitioning process via that primitive UI can be bewildering. I fully expect to be bewildered again because it's been over a year since I last did it, but I'll add an answer summarizing my experience this time.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using Ubuntu with full disk encryption for over a year. The Alternate Install CD for Ubuntu 12.04 makes it easy. During the installation, when it asks you how you want to partition your disks, one of the options will say something like "Guided - set up LVM with encryption." Just select that one and it will do all of the advanced work for you. All you need to do is come up with a passphrase and you're set.

Comment: Just the answer I was looking for -- the alternate CD has the same options available as the Debian installer, which has included LVM with encryption for quite a while.

Answer (score 1):

Basically until you fully understand it, why take the big risk of doing it and risking data loss?  It is only a good idea if you have really sensitive data on a hard drive on a laptop that could go missing.  Otherwise your login password is going to give fair security.

Comment: Its very much just for learning at the moment, so I really want to do it no matter what the possible consequences. Also, I do foresee the need for full disk encryption in the near future.